# Failed to update the root certificat : cacert.pem

Tags: python, cloud, cluster-computing, openstack, openstack-nova

I use devstack to install openstack now, but unfortunately, i met a problem:

```
/home/my/devstack/tools/create_userrc.sh -PA --target-dir /home/my/devstack/accrc
ERROR: The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation. (HTTP 500)
Failed to update the root certificate: /home/my/devstack/accrc/cacert.pem
```

Can you tell me HOW TO FIX it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably means the nova-cert service is not running. You can find its screen in the devstack screen list under `n-crt`. Look for errors there.

If it has crashed because `"Table 'nova.services' doesn't exist"`, that could be due to extra db migration *.pyc files after a downgrade. Stop devstack, remove all `/opt/stack/nova/nova/db/sqlalchemy/migrate_repo/versions/*.pyc` files and restart devstack.